# Slideshow overflow-x not working

Tags: html, css, overflow, slideshow

I am trying to make a slideshow. The thumbs are horizontally positioned and when you click on one the big image changes. I can't seem to manage to get all my thumbnails next to each other and then use overflow-scroll: x to scroll trough the list.

Would anybody have a solution? I've putted a live preview online at http://www.warrebuysse.be/zoomzoomzoom/gallery.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need an extra wrapper inside div#gallery with width set to thumb_width * number_of_thumbs

Comment: And if the width of that extra wrapper is variable? What would be the best thing to do then? Get the entire width of all the images combined with javascript and update it like that?

Comment: yes, you'll need to set the width from js depending on the number of thumbs

Comment: I've written the Javascript and the images are perfectly aligned next to each other, but the overflow-x: scroll is still not working. I've uploaded the new version on the website.

Comment: removing display: table should fix it

Comment: also, when you set the width of the container, you'll also need to account for any margins between the thumbs